# How do I create a yaml file correctly with eo-yaml

Tags: java, yaml

With the help of the api https://github.com/decorators-squad/eo-yaml I create a yaml file however I have the problem that the file format does not fit as I would like to have them

How my config should look like:

```yaml
name: ali
age: unknown
gender: male
```

How my Config look:
`yaml  name: aliage: unknowngender: male`

**My create methode**

````java
for ( Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields() ) {
            if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }

            Object value = null;
            try {
                value = field.get(this);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            YamlMapping yaml = Yaml.createYamlMappingBuilder()
                    .add(field.getName(), value.toString()).build();

            try {
                fileWriter.write(yaml.toString());
                fileWriter.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }```

**My ConfigTest Class**

```java
@Configuration(name = "config.yml")
public class ConfigTest extends YamlConfig {

    private final String name = "ali";
    private final String age = "unknown";
    private final String gender = "male";

    public ConfigTest() {
        this.create();
    }
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `YamlMapping` for each key/value pair and immediately render it. So you render three separate mappings:

- `name: ali`
- `age: unknown`
- `gender: male`

Then, you concatenate them into a file. Since you do not add line breaks, they are all written to the same line.

What you actually want to do is to create *one* mapping that contains all three key/value pairs:

```java
YamlMappingBuilder builder = Yaml.createYamlMappingBuilder();
for ( Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields() ) {
    if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
    }

    Object value = null;
    try {
        value = field.get(this);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   builder.add(field.getName(), value.toString());
}
try {
    fileWriter.write(builder.build().toString());
    fileWriter.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hey @flyx thanks for the answer so I tried it as you explained it to me but unfortunately nothing happens in my config (the config is created but it is empty) why is that?

Comment: @Ali I put the code I skipped over in my answer which should work if the previous code worked. If it doesn't for you, you'll need to give us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since we cannot guess the parts of your code that would be needed to execute it.

Comment: here is my code(sorry i can't post the code otherwise)

[My createConfig Methode](https://just-paste.it/5h7Z5sh9rD/)

[My ConfigTest methode](https://just-paste.it/EHRAIysiaD/)

[My Bootstrap class](https://just-paste.it/tibSXrI1yS/)

Comment: @Ali Not sure if relevant but you did forget to `close()` the FileWriter.